# ExtJS: Create JSB3 file from protected url

Tags: javascript, extjs4, jsbuilder

I want to generate jsb3 files from a url like http://example.com/home. Its protected. Only logged in user can see this. People login in http://example.com/. The control panel (after login the '/home') is fully writen in ExtJS. Sencha tools can not access it as it does not have the cookie.

How can I create JSB3 file for such url?

I usually do this by

```
sencha create jsb -a http://example.com/home -p home.jsb3
```

But sencha needs to login. if there is a way to use existing cookie header. I could have used that.

An option to fix it is to download the url as a file and feed `sencha` this file as a local file. But it has problems. `sencha` throws error!

```
$ sencha create jsb -a home.html -p home.jsb3
Error thown from your application with message: TypeError: 'null' is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to depend on your application environment.  I have the same issue in a java environment and here's how we work around it.  You may be able to use a similar solution in your situation.

Our auth is managed by Shiro, so in our case that's where we work around anonymous users.  Shiro reads security information from a file that lists URLs and user roles that are allowed to access them.  Our configuration looks for that file in a standard location.  This is where we place the real security settings.  We can override that location by setting JVM properties when we launch the java server.

When we want to run sencha create, we launch a java server that points to a custom security file that allows anonymous access to all resources.  Now, phantom.js can load the page without authorization. (phantom.js the headless browser that sencha create uses to load the page).

We then run sencha create exactly as you specify above.

The downside to this is that we must make sure our applications do not throw exceptions for anonymous users.  Even though our applications will always require authentication, we need to make sure all of our JavaScript is properly loaded for anonymous users.